# Post on a Facebook Group using 2.0+ API, PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Even after having read Facebook Developer's FAQ I've many questions about the development of FB apps, permissions, reviews and so on.

I created my app because I wanted to use FB Login and FB id's to manage users of my (small) site; the site purpose is to organize matches between users of a game app (Aworded) and to post their result onto a FB Group of which my site's users ar members too

1) Do I really need to develop a FB app to reach this aim (edit: kinda rhetorical question...)?

2) I was able to do everything I wanted until the upgrade of my app to version 2.0; now, with basic permissions, I'm not able to publish comments on FB Group through my site/app. What permission do I need to post my site's users comments on the FB Group I administrate? Is it `publish_action`?

3) I'm trying to obtain this permission through Facebook Review, but every time they answer me that instructions I'm giving cannot be reproduced: how can I show them a "post on Group through my app example", if I don't have yet that permission?

4) Together with the negative response to the permission request, I received another negative one about the possibility to insert my app in the App Center: I don't think I'm interested in publishing my app in the app center (is a "members only" app...): how can I specify that I'm not interested in that? Will my app still usable by everyone connecting to my site?

Sorry for the many questions, but I really need to clarify my ideas on these arguments, and traditional FAQ are not helping me...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Yes, of course you need an App for FB Login and posting and all that stuff. How else would you implement FB Login and how else would you get Facebook IDs or post to a group?

2) You need `user_managed_groups` and `publish_actions`, as you can read in the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/group/feed#publish

3) If only you are using the permission, you don´t need to go throught the review process. You can just authorize yourself with the permissions and store the [Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens). Be aware that an Extended User Token only lasts for 60 days.

4) If you don´t want your App to show up in the App Center, just don´t submit it ;)

Comment: 2) Is the `user_managed_groups` really necessary to just publish for the user on a Group of which he's a member?
3) Mmm... I can publish a post on a Group logging as myself, of course but... what should I show to FB guys? A working example of my site or a screenshot of my post published on FB Group?.. I created a working example but, of course, it works just if you have the permission...
4) Well, im's submitting my request for the permission... where am I exactly asking for the App Center thing? What's the way of NOT asking it? ;)

Comment: 2) yes. but the user MUST be a moderator of the group too. there is user_groups too, but you will not get it approved and afaik there are plans to remove it completely

Comment: 3) you can also present screenshots and a video to the review team. also, they will use a test user if there is one, so they WILL be able to get the permissions

Comment: 4) app center submission and login review are 2 different things. if you are sure you did not submit, just ignore it.

Comment: About App Center request: the only option I found was the one saying "Do you want your app to be public, or do you want to use it as a test app?" (or something similar): I chose the "public" option (because I want my app to be used by other users than me...), could it be this related to the App Center request? (I don't think so...)

Comment: so, what permission do I need If I want my app to publish comments for my user on a group of which they are members but NOT admins? With `user_managed_groups` and `publish_actions` it seems that ONLY admins can publish. (Onestly I'm still wondering why publishing on a group has become so difficult.. :( )

Comment: there is no way to do that anymore. you would need user_groups, but that permission may be removed sooner or later and you will not get it approved.

Comment: it´s for spam reasons. user_groups was mostly used to spam groups. non-admins should not post to groups at all with the api, they can just go to the group and post manually.

Answer (score 3):

As of latest changes to Graph API from August 1st, 2018, 
permissions `user_managed_groups` and `publish_actions` are deprecated, and now 
there are new permissions required for posting to groups:

`publish_to_groups` and `groups_access_member_info`. 
In addition to this, Facebook app will be allowed to list all user's groups.
To list groups only where user is administrator or moderator, using `me/groups` endpoint, 
a `privacy` field should be added among other fields to retrieve for each group.

Comment: Can I publish in groups to which I belong or only in groups that I administered?